# how to retrieve data from database and put to component

Tags: database

I need to retrieve data from content database and put the data to specific component in tridion content GUI itself. How it is possible?

Comment: I'd recommend doing some research then coming back with a more specific question.

Comment: There are some order form submitted from the websites. and we need to maintained the order request (create/edit/delete data) through Tridion. I thought the best approach is to store data to database first and then from tridion we can retrieve the data (may be with the help of some template code or the help of web service) and put the data to the component. After that we can publish the respective page to the file server and user will be able to view the order data to the websites.This is the main scenario here. Am i clear now John? Now my question is whether this approach is possible or not?

Comment: Hi Soubhik. Instead of providing that information in a comment, can you edit the question and add it. There's a helpful "edit" link right under the question. Doing so might also get rid of some of those downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

As a CMS, Tridion can manage and integrate content from practically any source in the Content Manager, during publish, or in delivery.

Though an order fulfillment use case is possible with a CMS, there are a few strong business reasons to avoid this approach. Your initial idea for a separate database is probably a better, more secure fit.

1. **In the Content Manager**. Orders are visitor specific and may need more authorization than you'll find in a CMS. Tridion gives you detailed authorization settings down to the folder or organizational item, rather than per visitor (or per order).
2. **Fulfillment**. Orders need to be reviewed and processed by the appropriate departments, which aren't typically CMS users. Though CMS users might review statistics, promote products/solutions, or moderate website comments, editing orders (as Components) probably shouldn't be a Web Content Management task.
3. **Publishing**. Publishing pages is a poor fit for displaying order status, which needs to be specific to (logged in) visitors. Pages would mean anyone could see any order with the right URL.

Though a CMS may have all the parts (and APIs) for this use case, it's better at handling managed content, layout, and page structure rather than individual orders.

If there's confusion on the term "component" and you mean to integrate a store or fulfillment application in the CMS, it's definitely possible to have [displays in Tridion without the data being in Tridion](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/05/cm-side-integrations-mocked-up.html).

Comment: Alvin thx for the reply. I also think Whether Web-forms can be a good approach here. We can create order from or any other form as a component with the help of web-form designer and then data can be submitted with the help webform server to back end database.