# TBB code needed to fetch data from database

Tags: 2011

Is it possible to retrieve any data from database and store the data into specific components in Tridion through TBB in Content Manager portion?

Comment: I wish you ask your organization to arrange training for SDL Tridion. From your question it seems there are some basic gaps in understanding about what SDL Tridion is and what you are trying to ask. It would be great and allows the community to help you if you can share your scenario in the question well in terms of Tridion keywords and also what so far you have done.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/7696/46

Answer (score 2):

If I understood at all what you are trying to do, I would still suggest that TBB will not be a good option for you. I am not sure why you want to do this but you can follow below process (may not be recommended by many):

- Write an Event Code on Pre-Component Save
- Fetch Data from the database and update the Fields (or Component XML)

If it is something related to saving the data while publishing the Component Presentation then you can think of multiple ways:

- TBBs
- Deployer Extension
- Storage Extension etc.

Depending on specific business context you may have.

Hope this give some headway for necessary training that you may need.